# "zypper install python-mysqldb mysql-server" Packages not found

Tags: python, mysql, openstack, opensuse, zypper

http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/basics-database-controller.html

I am following this guide using OpenSuse 13.1. The guide is intended for Ubuntu but I am trying to find the OpenSuse equivalents.

```
zypper install python-mysqldb mysql-server
```

Results in:

```
Package 'python-mysqldb' not found.

'mysql-server' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.

No provider of 'mysql-server' found.
```

What are the equivalents of these in OpenSuse which will allow OpenStack to run (just testing it out)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe OpenSuSE is using mariadb, try:

```
zypper in mariadb python-mysql
```

You might find useful information on the OpenSuSE openstack development page, and in the openstack docs respectively:

https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:OpenStack

http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/zypper/content/